# Securing mysql passwords in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following database

```
`database`
id | domain        | db_user | db_pass | db_name
------------------------------------------------------
1  | domainone.com | root    | root    | domain_one

// MORE DATABASES HERE
```

When I access `domainone.com`, I select domainone.com's database infos and connect to the new database.

The problem is, how I can "safe" the password, which curretly is in raw mode?

**UPDATE**

I want to know how to store the password that **lets you get to other database** in database. So, I can't hash and verify hash, as I know.

Comment: Is this the mysql USER table or a table of your own ?

Comment: You could use [AES_Enrypt and AES_Decrypt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html) but you will have to figure out how to safely store the encryption key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your structure to:

```
`database`
id | domain        | db_user | db_pass | pass_iv | db_name
------------------------------------------------------
1  | domainone.com | root    | root    | ....... | domain_one

// MORE DATABASES HERE
```

The additional column `pass_iv` will hold the [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) used to encrypt that particular password.

Here is some sample PHP code to do the encryption and decryption in a more secure manner than using MySQL's [AES_ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) function.

```
<?php

$mysqlPass = '12345thispassword$'; // this is the password you want to store

$key    = 'this is a secure secret key...';  // a secure secret key for encryption
$cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$mode   = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;

$keysize = mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher, $mode);
$ivsize  = mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, $mode);
$iv      = mcrypt_create_iv($ivsize);  // create random IV for encryption

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, $mysqlPass, $mode, $iv); // encrypt pass
```

At this point, insert the `$encrypted` password into your database along with the `$iv` used to encrypt the password (into `pass_iv` columnn).

To decrypt:

```
$key    = 'this is a secure secret key...';  // a secure secret key for encryption
$cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$mode   = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
$keysize = mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher, $mode);

// read password info from db...this includes the encrypted pass and pass_iv

// put encrypted password into $encrypted, put pass_iv into $iv

$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt($cipher, $key, $encrypted, $mode, $iv);
$decrypted = rtrim($decrypted, "\0");

// decrypted is now the plain-text database password.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm you have a pretty severe key storage problem here that you've neglected to address. In fact this solution is perhaps worse then the original problem since it secures nothing but looks like it does.

Comment: Well one would hope the database server is isolated from the web server so if one was hacked, the other is still secure.  The key could come from anywhere though, preferably its stored in a secure file and accessed via a web-service or read securely into PHP.  It's just a start to demonstrate how to encrypt values to put into the database.

Comment: If one is worried about storing plain text in the DB the assumption is that it's already compromised.

Answer (score -1):

You should apply a hashing algorithm before saving it in the database.

To check a password, just apply the same algorithm  and check the hash against the one stored in the DB.

Make sure you choose a good algorithm and salt value!

Comment: I want to know how to store the password that lets you get to other database in database.

Comment: You're thinking of a different use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use md5 to crypt your password and to save in database. And when you check the password crypt the password that enter in form and compare with that in database.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an explanation of how password hashing works in MySQL - 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html